# mac firewall will not opening up for nginx

Tags: macos, nginx

I am trying to allow connections to mac running nginx on port 8080. I have tried to use the UI for setting the firewall. Also tried to use the terminal - nothing worked?

```
sudo /usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw --add /usr/local/Cellar/nginx/1.8.0/bin/nginx
```

Everything works fine when I turn off the firewall.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting normally in daemon mode does not seem to bind nginx to the firewall

```
$ sudo nginx
```

Starting in non-daemon mode does bind to the firewall and MacOS would prompt you to add/deny the firewall rule.

```
$ sudo nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

You can also debug the firewall log file while your external connections try to connect to nginx

```
$ sudo tail -f /var/log/appfirewall.log
```

You'll want to see both `LISTEN` and `CONNECT` in the log:

```
Jun 21 17:11:17 MacBook socketfilterfw[1645] <Info>: nginx: Allow TCP LISTEN  (in:0 out:4)
Jun 21 17:11:17 MacBook socketfilterfw[1645] <Info>: nginx: Allow TCP CONNECT (in:1 out:0)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you using nginx from brew, just run nginx with `sudo` param:

`$ sudo brew services start nginx`

then firewall ask you to allow in connections.

Note: if you run same command but with no sudo, firewall not allowed connection.